# java biginteger not working

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

input text
5
1
5
7
10
123456789123456789

To use the binginteger because the input value is large

Does not work on 123456789123456789.
I don't know which is wrong.

For game method, two people first decide a positive integer N and have an x that is initialized with a 1.

Alice starts the game first, and then, taking turns, she does the following work on her own.

Replace x with 2x or 2x + 1.

When x is larger than N (over), the person who did the work is defeated.

My code is below.

```
public static Boolean result(int X, BigInteger N) {
    if(X == 0)
        return false;
    else if(X % 2 == 0) {
        BigInteger check = BigInteger.valueOf((int)((3*Math.pow(2,X)-1)/2));
        if(check.compareTo(N) == 1 || check.compareTo(N) == 0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

public static int returnX(BigInteger N) {
    int X = 0;
    while(true) {
        if((BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2,X)).compareTo(N) == -1 
                || BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2,X)).compareTo(N) == 0)
                && N.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2,X+1))) == -1)
            break;
        X++;
    }
    return X;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T;
    T = sc.nextInt();
    BigInteger[] N = new BigInteger[T];

    for (int test_case = 1; test_case <= T; test_case++) {
        N[test_case-1] = sc.nextBigInteger();
    }

    for (int test_case = 1; test_case <= T; test_case++) {
        if(result(returnX(N[test_case-1]),N[test_case-1])) {
            System.out.printf("#%d Alice\n",test_case);
        }
        else
            System.out.printf("#%d Bob\n",test_case);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do *all* the math in `BigInteger`.  For example,

```
 BigInteger.valueOf((int)((3*Math.pow(2,X)-1)/2))
```

should instead be

```
BigInteger.valueOf(3)
    .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(x))
    .subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
    .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2))
```

...and so on through the rest of your program.  If you're doing any math inside a call to `BigInteger.valueOf`, it's probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In function return X, you wrote

```
if((BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2,X)).compareTo(N) == -1 
            || BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2,X)).compareTo(N) == 0)
            && N.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf((int)Math.pow(2,X+1))) == -1)
```

it will be smaller than N forever

so try this instead:

```
if((BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(X).compareTo(N) == -1
                || BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(X).compareTo(N) == 0)
                && N.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(X+1)) == -1)
```

it will work